# Filling a List in a Model from a database table

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3

Subject Models

```
  public class Subject : TObject
  {
     piblic string SubjectID   {get; set; } 
     public string FirstName   {get; set; }
     public string LastName    {get; set; }
     public bool   IsT         {get; set; }
     public DateTime EntryDate {get; set; }
     public List<Address> Addresses  {get; set; }
  }
```

Model for List Addresses

```
  public class Addresses : TObject
  {
     public string SubjectID      {get; set; }
     public string Street1        {get; set; }
     public string City           {get; set; }
     public string State          {get; set; }
     public string Zip            {get; set; }
     public string Country        {get; set; }
  }
```

Can I read a database table into the Subject Model that contains everything except for the LIST, then read the second table into Addresses model, and then do a .add of the model to the LIST in the Subject Model? Basicly I need to fill each element in the Model Subject from the database.

Comment: Sure you can.  Are you having a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework 5.0 can handle this automatically setting the collection as virtual.

Comment: I went back and added SubjectID, so that both clases would have a coomon reference. I have a database table that contains address data. It is keyed to SubjectID. I need to now to be able to pull from the database using SubjectID into Addresses. Next I need to add this to the List in Subject. I tried doing the following but with no results. SubjectDB subjectdb = new SubjecDB(); BeaconDBEntities db = new BeaconDBEntities(); var Addresses = subjectdb.Addresses.First(x => x.SubjectID == model.SubjectID);

Comment: Have you set the foreign key attribute?